# Window settings for Google Maps widget

Tags: google-maps

I've got a plain-vanilla google maps widget sitting in a page and I'd like it if the driving directions opened up in a new window instead of taking over the current window.  Is there a setting for this?

Answer (score 0):

The driving directions go into whatever HTML element you specify as the second argument when you construct the GDirections object. So I guess that means you'd have to create the window before you create the GDirections object, which is likely not what you want.

The other thing that jumps out, looking at the documentation, is that you can call the load() method with the option getSteps = true. It's not clear what the "steps" data looks like, but I assume it essentially comes back as an HTML string. (Actually, it's not even clear how you *get* the data in the first place, but I assume it's GDirections.getSteps() or something similar.) So then when the "load" event happens, you can create the new window then put the "steps" data in it.